# StructureMap IRegistrationConvention to register non default naming convention?

Tags: configuration, structuremap

I currently have a bunch of repositories like so

IMyRepository
IAnotherRepository

They all inherit from IRepository (if this helps)

How can I get structuremap to use an IRegistryConvention scanner to register my concrete types which are named

SqlMyRepository
SqlAnotherRepository

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had read that article but it didn't give me quite what I needed. The AddAllTypesOf registered all the concrete types against the IRepositoryInterface but instead I require that each concrete type is registered against the interface with equivilent naming. 
ie.

```
For<IMyRepository>().Use<SqlMyRepository>();
```

Also I need to create some named instances for test repositories.

```
For<IMyRepository>().Use<TestMyRepository>().Named("Test");
```

Here's what I came up with which appears to work as I need it.

```
public class SqlRepositoryConvention : StructureMap.Graph.IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        // only interested in non abstract concrete types that have a matching named interface and start with Sql           
        if (type.IsAbstract || !type.IsClass || type.GetInterface(type.Name.Replace("Sql", "I")) == null)
            return;

        // Get interface and register (can use AddType overload method to create named types
        Type interfaceType = type.GetInterface(type.Name.Replace("Sql","I"));
        registry.AddType(interfaceType, type);
    }
}
```

And implemented as follows

```
Scan(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.TheCallingAssembly();
                cfg.Convention<SqlRepositoryConvention>();
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2009/01/20/create-your-own-auto-registration-convention-with-structuremap.aspx

In particular, this part

```
        container = new Container(x =>

        {

            x.Scan(o =>

            {

                o.TheCallingAssembly();
                o.AddAllTypesOf<IController>().NameBy(type => type.Name.Replace("Controller", ""));

            });

        });
```

So for you, I think something like this should work

```
        container = new Container(x =>

        {

            x.Scan(o =>

            {

                o.TheCallingAssembly();
                o.AddAllTypesOf<IRepository>().NameBy(type => type.Name.Replace("I", "Sql"));

            });

        });
```