# Custom construction with open generics in StructureMap

Tags: c#, generics, structuremap

I have a typical repository interface, `IRepository<T>`, and lots of concrete repositories.  Most of the concrete repositories look like this:

```
class ConcreteRepository<T> : IRepository<T> { .. }
```

These are easy to register with StructureMap:

```
For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(ConcreteRepository<>));
```

However, a select few of my concrete repositories look like this:

```
class AbnormalRepository<T1, T2> : IRepository<T1>, IAbnormal<T2> { .. }
```

I still want to use these abnormal repositories as `IRepository<T>`s, so for these I'm currently using special rules:

```
// this sucks!
For(typeof(IRepository<Foo1>)).Use(typeof(AbnormalRepository<Foo1, Bar1>));
For(typeof(IRepository<Foo2>)).Use(typeof(AbnormalRepository<Foo2, Bar2>));
```

It would be nice if I could just specify a function that StructureMap could use to construct my repositories, since I know that all of my abnormal repositories implement `IAbnormal<T>`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom IRegistrationConvention and call it from within the Scan() method of your container configuration.

You can see an example of this discussed on another stackoverflow question:

[StructureMap IRegistrationConvention to register non default naming convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379680/structuremap-iregistrationconvention-to-register-non-default-naming-convention)

You can also see a number of IRegistrationConvention examples within the StructureMap source code itself.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a custom registration convention because it changes how we're currently initializing StructureMap.  It does work in my tests, though, which is certainly a good thing.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not following your use case all the way, but you can use a function (lambda actually) to construct your object. Use either of the two overloads:

```
// lambda with no params
For<IRepository<Foo1>>().Use(() => { ... });
// context is a StructureMap SessionContext
For<IRepository<Foo1>>().Use(context => { ... });
```

To see what is available off SessionContext, check out http://structuremap.github.com/structuremap/UsingSessionContext.htm

**ADDED:**

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using StructureMap;

namespace SMTest2
{
    public interface IRepository<T> {}
    public class AbnormalRepository<T,T2> : IRepository<T>{ }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestOpenGeneric
    {
        private IContainer _container   ;

        [SetUp]
        public void DescribeContainer()
        {
            _container = new Container(cfg => 
                cfg.For(typeof (IRepository<>)).Use(ctx => new AbnormalRepository<String, int>()));
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestItWorks()
        {
            var stringVector = _container.GetInstance(typeof (IRepository<>));
            Assert.IsInstanceOf<AbnormalRepository<String,int>>(stringVector);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem is the `For<IRepo<>>()` method doesn't exist - open generics seem to require the `For(typeof(IRepo<>))` method.  The session context overload is available, however, so that seems like a good start.  Unfortunately, my test `For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(c => new AbnormalRepository<Foo, Bar>())` (followed by a `GetInstance<IRepository<Foo>>()`) didn't work, saying I declared no default instance of `IRepository<Foo>`.

Comment: Whatever type you pass to GetInstance, has to match how you registered it.  In your example, you said you registered IRepository<>, but asked for IRepository<Foo>.

Comment: I think I get your problem now, as Joshua says above, you have to create a custom convention http://structuremap.github.com/structuremap/ScanningAssemblies.htm#section8