# StructureMap configure concrete classes whose interface names don't match

Tags: c#, structuremap

Given concrete classes and interfaces having names that don't match

```
Harvester_JohnDeere_Parsley : AbstractMachine, IParsleyHarvester
Harvester_NewHolland_Sage : AbstractMachine, ISageHarvester
Harvester_Kubota_Rosemary : AbstractMachine, IRosemaryHarvester
```

where the interfaces have a common parent

```
IParsleyHarvester : ISpiceHarvester
ISageHarvester : ISpiceHarvester
IRosemaryHarvester : ISpiceHarvester
```

how can StructureMap be configured so that instances of I...Harvester can be injected into the constructor e.g.

```
public ParsleyField(IParsleyHarvester parsleyHarvester)
```

without having to configure each pair individually in the Registry? e.g.

```
For<ISageHarvester>().Use<Harvester_NewHolland_Sage>();
```

I've tried scanning

```
Scan(x =>
{
    x.AssemblyContainingType<Harvester_Kubota_Rosemary>();
    x.AddAllTypesOf<ISpiceHarvester>();
```

but the I...Harvester interfaces don't get mapped.

Thanks!

**edit**:

Both answers work. @jeroenh's has the advantage that guard clauses can be added to exclude classes (for whatever reason). Here's an example based on @Mac's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379680/structuremap-iregistrationconvention-to-register-non-default-naming-convention).

```
public class HarvesterConvention : StructureMap.Graph.IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        // only interested in non abstract concrete types
        if (type.IsAbstract || !type.IsClass)
            return;

        // Get interface
        var interfaceType = type.GetInterface(
            "I" + type.Name.Split('_').Last() + "Harvester");

        if (interfaceType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(
                "type", 
                type.Name+" should implement "+interfaceType);

        // register (can use AddType overload method to create named types
        registry.AddType(interfaceType, type);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
Scan(x =>
{
    x.AssemblyContainingType<Harvester_Kubota_Rosemary>();
    x.Convention<HarvesterConvention>();
    x.AddAllTypesOf<ISpiceHarvester>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StructureMap does not know about your convention. You need to tell it about it by adding a custom registration convention.  Implement the IRegistrationConvention interface, and add the convention to the assembly scanner:

```
Scan(x =>
  {
  x.Convention<MyConvention>();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I adapted a solution from @Kirschstein's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379680/structuremap-iregistrationconvention-to-register-non-default-naming-convention).

```
Scan(x =>
{
    x.AssemblyContainingType<Harvester_Kubota_Rosemary>();
    x.AddAllTypesOf<ISpiceHarvester>()
     .NameBy(type => "I" + type.Name.Split('_').Last() + "Harvester");
```

Defines the way to convert the concrete class's name into its interface name for lookup purposes.